# API call to force viewer to resize to constraints

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I have a resizable splitter pane (using AngularJS) that allows the user to drag to change its size. On one side of the splitter pane is the Forge Viewer div, contained inside the left pane div (they are not the same).

I'm using the "Split-Pane" library here and its associated AngularJS plugin.

https://github.com/shagstrom/split-pane

When I resize the splitter pane, the forge viewer does not resize completely - the UI elements move with the new right border, but the 3D view does not.

However, if I resize the browser window (drag it out of maximize, then re-maximize it), the viewer updates itself accordingly to the new split pane size.

Is there an API call to force the viewer to resize itself to its new constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `viewer.resize()`? I have used this in the past and resizes with no problem.

Comment: Hi Jaime. We try to stick to technical writing here, so it would help us volunteer editors if you could refrain from salutations, thanks, and other conversational material. Thanks!

Comment: Accepted solution, thank you! Wish it were easier to find in the Forge dox.

Comment: We are working on a better documentation to make this less painful. Thank you for your patiences! cheers!